# Android room one typeconverter for multiple enums?

Tags: enums, type-conversion, android-room

I have different enums in my Project:

Size (S, M, L, XL) and Color (Black, White, Red, Blue ...)

To save the enum in the database I need to have a typeconverter for all of them loke this:

```
        @TypeConverter
        public static Size getSize(int numeral){
            for(Size s : values()){
                if(s.numeral == numeral){
                    return s;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @TypeConverter
        public static Integer getSizeInt(Size size){
            return size.numeral;
        }
```

It works as expected, but I like to know if it was possible to write only one general typeconverter that I can use for all of my enums?

Thank you!

Kev

Answer (score 1):

this is a super late answer. I just had same problem with you ([Android Room type convert multiple enum types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102431/android-room-type-convert-multiple-enum-types)). In short, no, Room doesn't support generic converters at the moment. You will have to create a converter for each of your enum classes. Something like the following

```
object EnumATypeConv {

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toOrdinal(type: EnumA): Int = type.ordinal

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toEnumA(ordinal: Int): EnumA = EnumA.values().first { it.ordinal == ordinal }
}
```